# ClassTemplate generation in VS 2008 with T4 or other technology

Tags: templates, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, code-generation, t4

I have created an AddInHost with which I can extend the VS Ide commands (right click on SolutionExplorerMenu).

Now I want to use the AddIn to generate code from a template.

I've reading many articles about T4 code generation and tried some simple templates, but I don't see how I can use the T4 technic in my AddIn.

For the templates I need to specify some parameters which I can use in the template.
I need parameters for

- Namespace
- ClassName
- Methodcollection
- PropertyCollection

I tried to use

```
<#@ property name="ClassName"  type="System.String"  processor="PropertyProcessor" #>
```

but after I read some articles I thought it should not be worked correctly.

My problem is that I can't find a solution to work with T4 and my AddIn.

All commands in the Addin have one "Perform" method where all the command specific implementation is written.
In the command I have a reference to the host (=VS IDE) so I can use the IDE model completly.

How can I use T4 in my AddIn to create a file based on a template?
How is the way I should do it?
Should I add the file to the destination project via `ProjectItems.AddFromFile()`
or can I use features of T4?

I am a little bit confused how I can implement my requirements.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ITextTemplating service. Here is [why](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/05/t4-architecture/).

Comment: That is how i tried it before, but i didnt see how i can combine the ITextTemplating with my CommandAction?
Should i create my custom "ITextTemplatingEngineHost" when i use the Engine?
Should i create the Engine/Host via ServiceProvider or directly via "new" initialization?